# how to start a counter from scratch that shows online

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a script on my site that shows (the online counter of the server players in GTA) without refreshing the page. [counter script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtD7z.jpg)

```
var updateInterval = 700;
setInterval(updatePlayerCount, updateInterval);

// Function to run update logic
function updatePlayerCount() {
      var ip = "rage2.grand-rp.su:22005";
    $.getJSON('https://cdn.rage.mp/master', function(masterlist) {
        $.each(masterlist, function(key, result) {
            if(key == ip) {
                document.getElementById('online').innerHTML = result.players;
                return false;              
            }
        });
   });
}
```

It should work so that when the page loads, the counter starts from zero and up to the number that is online now.

I found such a code, the counter starts from zero on page load and goes up to the number that is in the html, but it works separately with the code above. How to make them work together? 
[starting counter from zero to number in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HVVC.jpg)

```
 $('#online').each(function () {
$(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
  Counter:$(this).text()
},{
  duration: 4000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function(now){
    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your counter code to a function then add that function into the `getJSON` callback. Also you don't need the each if you are looking for one record, you can just see if that IP exists as a key.

```
var updateInterval = 700;
_timer = setInterval(updatePlayerCount, updateInterval);

function ShowCounter() {
  clearInterval(_timer);
  $('#online').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
}

function updatePlayerCount() {
  var ip = "rage2.grand-rp.su:22005";
  $.getJSON('https://cdn.rage.mp/master', function(masterlist) {
         if(masterlist[ip] != undefined){
              document.getElementById('online').innerHTML = masterlist[ip].players;
              ShowCounter();
         }

  });
}
```

Comment: thanks, I would like to stop the automatic update of online, how can I fix it?

Comment: I posted this on jsfigle https://jsfiddle.net/k43fcd8m/14/

Comment: @GRANDMASTER I updated my answer, you set the interval with a timer, then use clearinterval(var). Just move that function call to where you need it.

Comment: I still don't have online auto-update, could you please help?

Comment: @GRANDMASTER by disabling the interval, you disabled the function that auto updates. Although ajax isn't the best option for that anyway. If you want something to auto update after the page is done loading, I would recommend asking a new question since this was related to getting the counter working, not getting an auto update working. There are better options vs ajax for constantly downloading updates.